# WorksheetFunction.countif criteria not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to create an email list of unique emails. The list has a lot of duplicates, but I only want them once. Some of the rows have not been assigned an email so they show as <UNASSIGNED> and I want to ignore those.

I have used this in another sheet where it is working well, the difference is that on this new application I need to copy the data to a temporary location, because it is filtered and the `CountIf` does not work on filtered rows.

The code is ignoring the criteria for the <UNASSIGNED>. I want to figure out, why this is happening.

I first use the `CountIf` to get the loan officer email list (MLO list). That works fine, but then the code to get the Processor list is not working as it should. The code below Processor list is supposed to ignore any value that equals <UNASSIGNED>, but it doesn't:

```
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
  lastSrcRw = Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
     For Each cell In Sheets("Pipeline").Range("E11:E" & lastSrcRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dstRw = dstRw + 1
        cell.Copy Sheets(2).Range("A" & dstRw)
     Next

'Loop through Sheet2 list, extract unique addresses
  lastTmpRw = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For tmpRw = 1 To lastTmpRw
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & tmpRw), _
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & tmpRw)) < 2 Then
               addylist_tmp = addylist_tmp & Sheets(2).Range("A" & tmpRw).Value & "; "
         End If
     Next tmpRw

'Clean up temp addylist
     addylist = Left(addylist_tmp, Len(addylist_tmp) - 2)
     'MsgBox addylist

'Processor List
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
  lastSrcRw = Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
     For Each cell In Sheets("Pipeline").Range("C11:C" & lastSrcRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dstRw = dstRw + 1
        cell.Copy Sheets(2).Range("D" & dstRw)
     Next

'Loop through Sheet2 list, extract unique addresses
  lastTmpRw = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
     For tmpRw = 1 To lastTmpRw
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("D1:D" & tmpRw), "<>" & "<UNASSIGNED>") Then
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("D1:D" & tmpRw), Sheets(2).Range("D" & tmpRw)) < 2 Then
                addylist_tmp2 = addylist_tmp2 & Sheets(2).Range("D" & tmpRw).Value & "; "
         End If
         End If
     Next tmpRw

'Clean up temp addylist
     addylist2 = Left(addylist_tmp2, Len(addylist_tmp2) - 2)
```

Comment: `"<>" & "<UNASSIGNED>"`  is likely to be the problem.  Imagine if it was in a formula.  It would like like `countif(D:D,<><Unassigned>)`. That wouldn't work either.  Try putting putting double quotes around `"""<Unassigned>"""`. Just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried that as well as single quotes.

Comment: Hrmmm.  Ok.  I'll load up excel when I get home.  This should be an easy fix.

Comment: How about a quick copy of the range to a memory array, then looping to create a `Dictionary` of unique email addresses, easily ignoring your "<UNASSIGNED>" values. Then you have your count and can write the emails in the compiled dictionary to the destination worksheet.

Comment: Sounds good but I’m a noob and wouldn’t know how. Can you provide a sample to get me started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a simple solution from a user named Fluff in MrExcel forum:

```
Sub mecerrato()
Dim Cl As Range
Dim Mlst As String, Plst As String
Dim Mdic As Object, Pdic As Object

Set Mdic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Pdic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Sheets("Pipeline")
  For Each Cl In .Range("C11", .Range("C" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
     If Cl.Value <> "" And Cl.Value <> "<UNASSIGNED>" Then Pdic(Cl.Value) = Empty
     If Cl.Offset(, 2).Value <> "" Then Mdic(Cl.Offset(, 2).Value) = Empty
  Next Cl
End With
Mlst = Join(Mdic.Keys, "; ")
Plst = Join(Pdic.Keys, "; ")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the row counter before reusing it on a different column.

You need  `dstRw = 0` on a line above `'Processor List`

Like this...

```
'Clean up temp addylist
     addylist = Left(addylist_tmp, Len(addylist_tmp) - 2)
     'MsgBox addylist

dstRw = 0

'Processor List
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
```

I think you might be getting confused by what's on `Sheet(2)` and what your result really is.  Your result is stored in `addylist2`

Here is the complete running code I used to test.  Only minor modifications from yours because I don't have your data.

Result in `addylist2` is `123` all filtered and excluded criteria are ignored.

```
Sub aaa()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastTmpRw As Long
Dim addylist_tmp As String
Dim addylist_tmp2 As String
Dim tmpRw As Long
Dim dstRw As Long
Dim lastSrcRw As Long
Dim addylist As String
Dim addylist2 As String

Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
  lastSrcRw = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
     For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("E11:E" & lastSrcRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dstRw = dstRw + 1
        cell.Copy Sheets(2).Range("A" & dstRw)
     Next

'Loop through Sheet2 list, extract unique addresses
  lastTmpRw = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For tmpRw = 1 To lastTmpRw
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & tmpRw), _
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & tmpRw)) < 2 Then
               addylist_tmp = addylist_tmp & Sheets(2).Range("A" & tmpRw).Value & "; "
         End If
     Next tmpRw

'Clean up temp addylist
     addylist = Left(addylist_tmp, Len(addylist_tmp) - 2)
     'MsgBox addylist

dstRw = 0

'Processor List
Sheets(2).Cells.ClearContents
  lastSrcRw = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
     For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("C11:C" & lastSrcRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dstRw = dstRw + 1
        cell.Copy Sheets(2).Range("D" & dstRw)
     Next

'Loop through Sheet2 list, extract unique addresses
  lastTmpRw = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
     For tmpRw = 1 To lastTmpRw
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("D1:D" & tmpRw), "<>" & "<UNASSIGNED>") Then
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("D1:D" & tmpRw), Sheets(2).Range("D" & tmpRw)) < 2 Then
                addylist_tmp2 = addylist_tmp2 & Sheets(2).Range("D" & tmpRw).Value & "; "
         End If
         End If
     Next tmpRw

'Clean up temp addylist
     addylist2 = Left(addylist_tmp2, Len(addylist_tmp2) - 2)
Sheet3.Cells.Clear
Sheet3.Cells(1, 1) = addylist
Sheet3.Cells(2, 1) = addylist2

End Sub
```

[image: Filtered Data Set]

Comment: It is still including  <UNASSIGNED> in the variable

Comment: I have it test on my machine, I'll paste my code so you can see what's changed.

Comment: I have tested and retested your code on my machine.  It works.  If you still have a problem then it is most likely caused by something that isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to determine the range of cells that holds the email addresses. My solution builds on that to create a `Dictionary` of unique email addresses, and as an added bonus performs some quick validation on the format of the text string that you "think" is an email address.

First, to validate the text string as a check for the email address format I created a function that looks first for the `@` character and then makes sure the portion of text to the right of the separator has at least one dot.

```
Private Function IsValidEmailFormat(ByVal thisText As String) As Boolean
    IsValidEmailFormat = False
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(thisText, "@")
    If UBound(tokens) = 1 Then
        '--- we found the domain separator, do we have a dot?
        tokens = Split(tokens(1), ".")
        If UBound(tokens) >= 1 Then
            '--- we found the dot, looks like an email address
            IsValidEmailFormat = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Next, we'll use that function to build our `Dictionary` from the given range. You'll see that within this function, we copy the given range into a memory-based array (read more about it [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array)). After that and making sure we have a string that is a valid email format, check to see it it's already in the dictionary -- this is how we can guarantee we have a list of UNIQUE email addresses.

```
Private Function GetUniqueEmails(ByRef thisRange As Range) As Dictionary
    Dim theseEmails As Dictionary
    Set theseEmails = New Dictionary

    '--- copy to memory array
    Dim thisData As Variant
    thisData = thisRange

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(thisData, 1) To UBound(thisData, 1)
        If IsValidEmailFormat(thisData(i, 1)) Then
            If Not theseEmails.Exists(thisData(i, 1)) Then
                theseEmails.Add thisData(i, 1), i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetUniqueEmails = theseEmails
End Function
```

Finally, as called from the main code logic, you can do what you want with the resulting list. I formed a semi-colon separated list similar to your example.

Here's the whole example code in a single block:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()
    Dim emails As Dictionary
    Set emails = GetUniqueEmails(Sheet3.Range("A1:A5"))

    '--- convert the emails to a semi-colon separated list for later use
    Debug.Print "there are " & emails.Count & " emails in the list"
    Dim emailList As String
    Dim email As Variant
    For Each email In emails.Keys
        emailList = emailList & email & ";"
    Next email
    emailList = Left(emailList, Len(emailList) - 1) 'remove the trailing ";"
End Sub

Private Function GetUniqueEmails(ByRef thisRange As Range) As Dictionary
    Dim theseEmails As Dictionary
    Set theseEmails = New Dictionary

    '--- copy to memory array
    Dim thisData As Variant
    thisData = thisRange

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(thisData, 1) To UBound(thisData, 1)
        If IsValidEmailFormat(thisData(i, 1)) Then
            If Not theseEmails.Exists(thisData(i, 1)) Then
                theseEmails.Add thisData(i, 1), i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetUniqueEmails = theseEmails
End Function

Private Function IsValidEmailFormat(ByVal thisText As String) As Boolean
    IsValidEmailFormat = False
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(thisText, "@")
    If UBound(tokens) = 1 Then
        '--- we found the domain separator, do we have a dot?
        tokens = Split(tokens(1), ".")
        If UBound(tokens) >= 1 Then
            '--- we found the dot, looks like an email address
            IsValidEmailFormat = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```